# How to include package license information using Webpack?

Tags: webpack, bundle

I want to use NPM [react-icons](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons) package that distributed under MIT license on my webpage. I'm using Webpack as my build/bundling tool and when it runs in the production mode its spits out minified js file that includes all libraries and my code in the same bundle. I want to include [react-icons copyright and permissions notice](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/blob/master/LICENSE) before the actual [react-icons](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons) code in the bundle.

How it could be achieved using Webpack?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that you don't have to include the license text and copyrights of dependencies directly into your output chunks. An alternative is generating a so called "bill of materials" file that contains a list of every package used, including version, license identifier and license text (which might include the copyright) for every package.

Check out [webpack-license-plugin](https://github.com/codepunkt/webpack-license-plugin) if this sounds like a good idea.

If you have any questions about the usage, feel free to open issues or ask here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [webpack banner plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/banner-plugin/) for this.

Example *webpack.config.js*:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    /* ... other webpack config ... */

    plugins: [
        new webpack.BannerPlugin(
            'react-icons – copyright 2018 ' +
            'kamijin_fanta <kamijin@live.jp>')
    ]
};
```

This will make it so that each JavaScript bundle created by webpack starts with this comment:

```
/*! react-icons – copyright 2018 kamijin_fanta <kamijin@live.jp> */
```

Configuration options are explained in the [plugin's documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/banner-plugin/).

Comment: Thank you Patrick! Is it correct way to include license in the source code? I thought that you need to include license exactly before the code itself. I mean: if I have 5 libs bundled into one minified file, is it correct to pull 5 licenses altogether in the begging of the file? This concern is why i didn't used this plugin at the first place.

Comment: I‘m not an expert in licensing law, but afaik it’s not very common to include this info in js bundles at all. Most people just include it in the readmes of their source code repos on github, that’s what I also do for my own open source modules. But you may be right, the text of the mit license can be interpreted that way, that you have to include the copyright notes in your bundle. Surely interesting question, but not exactly what you asked originally

Comment: I think it depends on if you view the resulting "blob" an executable or source code. I would say executable.